# Multipe routes with same verb to .NET6 REST API controller

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swagger-3.0

Has been a while since the last time with .NET Core 2 where it seemed to work without any hazzle.

But since starting with .NET6 I seem to struggle to have ApiController with multiple routes.

Relevant ConfigureServices:

```
     services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
     services.AddSwaggerGen();    
     services.AddControllers().AddApplicationPart(typeof(TestController).Assembly);
```

The application part is required because the controllers are in a different assembly.

Relevant ConfigureApp:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
```

My controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet("Test1")]
    public IActionResult GetTest1()
    {
        return Ok(Array.Empty<string>());
    }

    [HttpGet("Test2")]
    public IActionResult GetTest2()
    {
        return Ok(Array.Empty<string>());
    }

    [HttpGet("Test3")]
    public IActionResult GetTest3()
    {
        return Ok(Array.Empty<string>());
    }

}
```

They show up in Swagger UI as intended.

[image]

But when I try to execute them I always get

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:5000/Test/Test1' \
  -H 'accept: */*'

404: Error Not Found
```

Addition: They are visible in the UI
Wrong: but not included in the generated swagger.json in the background.
Correct: Not showing up seems to be a caching issue with Edge browser.

If a create a weatherforecast sample from the templates and paste the controller into the new project it works as excpeted.

The interesting thing is it works if I change the routes:

```
[HttpGet("/Test1")]
[HttpGet("/Test2")]
[HttpGet("/Test3")]
```

It doesn't work if I manually add the controller name (seems I have to use one path from the root):

```
[HttpGet("/Test/Test1")]
[HttpGet("/Test/Test2")]
[HttpGet("/Test/Test3")]
```

Anyone knows what I am missing why this makes a differene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your sample starting with a new API project.
You miss to call `app.MapControllers()`.

The `AddSwaggerGen` is independent from the routing, so it found endpoints based on the controller, but this endpoints are not mapped if the `MapControllers` method is not called.

If you try to call the endpoint from `/swagger` page you will also found the 404 error.

This is the `Program.cs` that works on the test project:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddControllers();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

// app.UseHttpsRedirection();
// app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
// app.UseRouting(); // if you enable this line and disable the previous you got the 404 error
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.Run();
```

From [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0): "Apps typically don't need to call UseRouting or UseEndpoints".

Comment: thanks for your interest in helping me out. Yes you were right but unfortunatly I missed the call to MapControllers only in the post but not in the code. Updated the post and added some more insights I had so far.

Comment: I tried to split controller on an class library, but it seems to work. Here [the sample solution (on github)](https://github.com/roby70/WebApplicationAPITest)

Comment: Seems there may are some things hidden in our none standard setup I can't figure out so far. Thank you for the answers and effort.